# Sublime-like Text Editor over ssh

Tags: android, macos, ssh, text-editor

I can't help stop wondering if there is like a Sublime Text 2 Editor out there that will still retain its code syntax highlighting over `ssh`? I usually ssh to an iDevice or an Android device for some coding but over `ssh` the terminal only allows me either nano or vi for quick editing codes over the device so that I won't FTP from machine to device all the time. I love using Sublime Text 2 and its features. Over `ssh`, nano and vi does not have syntax highlighting at all. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your question is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, I believe my question is about software tools that could be helpful in software development. That's why I ask of any text editor like sublime text which could help me code like the way I do in sublime but the difference is over ssh. got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use Notepad++ with the NppFTP plugin. Go here for more info: https://notepad-plus-plus.org/

Comment: The question is about Android. Notepad++ is only available on Windows, right?

Comment: @youen As I understand the question, this person wants to send commands from a desktop environment to an Android device. Yes, Notepad++ is for Windows only.

Comment: Do'h, you're right, sorry, I understood it the wrong way. However stackoverflow won't let me remove the downvote unless you edit the question ; sorry about that (I'll do it if you edit). I'll also delete my answer which is inadequate, and search or create the question about the other direction (editing remote text files with an android device) which is the one interesting me.

Answer (score 0):

[CodeAnyWhere apps](https://codeanywhere.com/apps) is what you looking for. It has Sublime Text environment and also can edit files on your SSH server

Comment: this seems to work for servers hosted online. How about for local servers/virtual machines running locally? Have you tried that?